# Where would a question about Software releases go?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I've got some questions about releasing a software program I've developed.  I don't really see any Stack that's geared towards the business end of software, just Stacks geared towards coding.  Are business end-type questions not allowed?  If they are, where would they go?  I'm not looking to ask "legal" questions, they're more on the marketing/release vein.

Answer (score 3):

I've always thought there was a "business of software" site amongst us that our network somehow missed.

Where to ask your question depends on context.
Our network trends heavily towards technical subjects, so even a site more focused on a business-related topic will likely have **a strong component of software business expertise.**

- If your question is about licensing or similar issues closer related to using the code itself, it might be a good fit on [**Programmers SE**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)  where software licensing is on topic.
- If your question is truly a business-related question, we have a site for [**Startups**](http://startups.stackexchange.com) that might work.
- I should also mention we have a site dedicated to [**Law**](http://law.stackexchange.com) that can be a good host for more legal-centric issues.

Comment: Don't forget there is a site about [Open Source](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/) if you have questions about open source licensing.